# Show that $\prod_{p} (1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}(1-\frac{1}{p^s})^{-2})$ is a Dirichlet series

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

As a part of the proof that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} \mu (n)d(n) = \mathcal{O}(x e^{-c(\log x)^{1/10}}),$$
we first write the sum as $$\sum_{n} \frac{\mu (n)d(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p}(1-\frac{2}{p^s})$$ which is equivalent to $$\prod_{p} (1 - \frac{1}{p^s})^2(1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}(1-\frac{1}{p^s})^{-2}).$$
I need to show that the above product can be written as $\frac{g(s)}{\zeta^2 (s)}$ where $g(s)$ is a Dirichlet series absolutely convergent for $\Re(s) > 1/2$.
How can I show that $$\prod_{p} (1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}(1-\frac{1}{p^s})^{-2})$$ is equivalent to $g(s)$? Probably Euler product can solve this problem, but I am not sure how.

Comment: $1-p^{-2s}(1-p^{-s})^{-2}$ can be expanded into power series of $p^{-s}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Euler product formula, $$\zeta(s) = \prod_{p}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)}^{-1}$$

which means

$$\prod_{p}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)} = \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}.$$

Then taking your equation

$$\prod_p{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\right)^2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-2}\right)} = \frac{g(s)}{\zeta^2(s)},$$

we see that

$$\frac{1}{\zeta^2(s)} \cdot \prod_p{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-2}\right)} = \frac{g(s)}{\zeta^2(s)}.$$

And from here you can deduce your answer.

Comment: Actually the deduction part was my question. I figured out the calculations you wrote here before. I just wanted to how I can express $\prod_p{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}\left(1-\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-2}\right)}$ as Dirichlet series absolutely convergent for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1/2$

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood, I did originally think that’s what you were asking. Have you tried writing in the form $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2s}} \cdot \prod_{p\mid n}{\left(\frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}\right)^2}\right)}$$ and simplifying from there? Alternatively, you could write the product as $$\prod_{p}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}} - \frac{2}{p^{3s}} - \frac{3}{p^{4s}} - \ ...\right)}$$ and expand that into a Dirichlet series instead.

Comment: If you only need to write the product as **a** Dirichlet series, then you could use the above summation, which is convergent for $\mathrm{Re}(s) > 1/2
.$

Comment: Yes, I showed that $g(s)$ is equivalent to $\prod_{p}{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}} - \frac{2}{p^{3s}} - \frac{3}{p^{4s}} - \ ...\right)}$, but I was curious whether there's another way to write this like your first expression $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{2s}} \cdot \prod_{p\mid n}{\left(\frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}\right)^2}\right)}$. How did you derive the first expression?

Comment: I suggest with these sorts of products that you first try expanding out a couple terms to start with. This will help you figure out the sort of structure of the corresponding Dirichlet series. It’s hard to explain, but essentially, what you have in your product is a multiplicative function, which allows you to convert to a Dirichlet series fairly easily. The $\mu(n)$ term comes from the fact that you’re summing over all products of primes (squarefree integers), where the negative sign contributes as many $-1$s as there are prime divisors.

Comment: The $1/n^{2s}$ comes from the $1/p^{2s}$ term in the product. And the product within the summation, is the product over all prime divisors of $n$ of the $(1-p^s)^{-2}$ term which was in the product. We’re only interested in the prime divisors of $n$ because in your original product, these are what make up the values of $n$ themself.

Comment: Here is a link to the wiki page on multiplicative functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function

Comment: In general, you have that $$\prod_p{(1 - f(p))} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mu(n)\cdot f(n)},$$ when $f$ is a multiplicative function. Additionally, you have that $$\prod_p{(1 + f(p))} = \sum_{ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ n=1 \\ n \ \text{squarefree}}^{\infty}{f(n)}.$$ Both  of these results you can obtain by expanding out the brackets and using the definition of a multiplicative function.

Comment: Also, if you wanted to use the product $$\prod_p{\left(1 - \frac{1}{p^{2s}}  - \frac{2}{p^{3s}}  - \frac{3}{p^{4s}} - \ … \right)}$$ you could write it in the form $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{\lambda(n)}{n^s} \cdot \prod_{p \mid n}{\left(f_n(p) - 1\right)}}$$ where $f_n(p) := \text{the largest exponent $m$ such that $p^m \mid n$},$ and $\lambda(n)$ is Louville’s function - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_function